# Capture & display the error message on console

Tags: java, selenium, extract-error-message

[image]

How to get the text which is displayed as the error message in the screenshot attached ?
I could not inspect it.

**I tried using the below selenium java code but it failed:**

```
String ale=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
System.out.println(ale);
```

The error message displayed is

> `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException:no such alert`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: If you open the inspector first and then if you reproduce this error, do you see any change in DOM? Or you can try getting the whole body text using `String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();` or you can also use `String pageContent = driver.getPageSource();` and try to find if the error string is present.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the message and the state by using the JavascriptExecutor:**

***Note: You just need to provide the input WebElement for each input tag.***

**Code:**

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@type='email'])[2]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean isValidInput = (Boolean)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].checkValidity();", ele);
System.out.println(isValidInput);
String validationMessage = (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].validationMessage;", ele);
System.out.println(validationMessage);
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]